# Can't get rated courses, errors in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to do multi-search everything works, but I have a problem with top-rated courses. Its red lines on `$courseIds` and `$fieldOrder`. Can someone please help me why it doesn't work? I'm getting errors when trying to search rated and leveled courses.

```
<input  class="search-header-field" type="text" name="ratedLevel">
```

---

```
$itemsRated = DB::table('ratings')->select('course_id', 
    DB::raw('AVG(stars_rated) as count'))
    ->groupBy('course_id')->orderBy("count", 'desc')->get();

$courseIds = [];
foreach ($itemsRated as $item) {
    array_push($courseIds, $item->course_id);
}

$fieldOrder = join(", ", $courseIds);

$courses = Course::when(
    $r->level,
    function ($query, $level) {
        return $query->where('level', 'like', "%$level%");
    }
)
    ->when(
        $r->category,
        function ($query, $category) {
            return $query->where('course_category_id', 'like', "%$category%");
        }
    )
    ->when(
        $r->discount,
        function ($query, $discount) {
            return $query->where('discount', '!=', $discount);
        }
    )
    ->when(
        $r->ratedLevel,
        function ($query, $ratedLevel) {
            return $query->whereIn('id', $courseIds)
                ->where('level', 'like', "%$ratedLevel%")
                ->orderByRaw("FIELD(id, $fieldOrder)");
        }
    )
    ->when(
        $r->price && in_array($r->price, ['more-expensive', 'less-expensive']),
        function ($query) use ($r) {
            return $query->orderBy('price', $r->price == 'less-expensive' ? 'asc' : 'desc');
        },
        function ($query) {
            return $query->get();
        }
    )
    ->paginate(18);
```

##### Error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Comment: the error is in the first line of code, you cant do where course_id = DB:raw..

Comment: If you look at the rest of the error, it will tell you exactly where in the query the syntax error is. As @Mar says, it will be where you've asked it to do `WHERE course_id = AVG(stars_rated) as count` which is obviously nonsense.

Comment: Thanks all for response. but how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: i changed it to  $itemsRated = DB::table('ratings')->select('course_id', DB::raw('AVG(stars_rated) as count'))
                ->groupBy('course_id')->orderBy("count", 'desc')->get();  now i'm getting error  Undefined variable $courseIds
 it can't get courseIds and $fieldOrder in query

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem with rating courses now it's filters everything.

```
              $courses = Course::when($r->level, function ($query, $level) {
            return $query->where('level', 'like', "%{$level}%");
        })->when($r->category, function ($query, $category) {
            return $query->where('course_category_id', 'like', "%{$category}%");
        })->when($r->discount === null, function ($query) {
            return $query->where('discount', '!=', null);
        })->when($r->rate === true, function ($query) {
            $itemsRated = DB::table('ratings')->select('course_id', DB::raw('AVG(stars_rated) as count'))
                ->groupBy('course_id')->orderBy("count", 'desc')->get();
            $courseIds = [];
            foreach ($itemsRated as $item) {
                array_push($courseIds, $item->course_id);
            }
            $fieldOrder = join(", ", $courseIds);
            $query->whereIn('id', $courseIds)->orderByRaw("FIELD(id, $fieldOrder)");
        })->when($r->price && in_array($r->price, ['more-expensive', 'less-expensive']), function ($query) use ($r) {
            return $query->orderBy('price', $r->price == 'less-expensive' ? 'asc' : 'desc');
        }, function ($query) {
            return $query->statusOn()->order()->orderBy('id');
        })->paginate(18);
```